# Detect and remove Memory Leak in Linux Application

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

We have a a very large project which is basically an application which uses Linux Application programming and runs on PowerPC processor. This project was initially developed by another company. We acquired the project from the company and now we are maintaining the project.

The application is reported to have a lot of `memory leak` issue. Since this is a large project, it is not possible to go to each source code file and find out the memory leak. We have used Valgrid, mpatrol and other memory leak detection tools. These tools did not help much and the memory leak has not decreased by a significant percentage.

In this situation, how to go about to reduce the memory leak by a significant amount.Is there a `general method` which people use in these case to reduce the memory leak other than the memory leak detection tools like mentioned above.

Comment: The most powerful memory leak detector I ever used is [Valgrind with Memchecker](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks), I'm pretty surprised it didn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Valgrind belongs to the best tools for this tasks. If it does not work correctly, there might only be a couple of things you can still do.

- First question: What language is the application in? Valgrind is very good for C and C++, but will not help you with garbage collected or scripting language. So check the language first. There might be something similar for java, but I have not used that much java, so you would have to ask someone else.
- Play around a lot with the settings of valgrind. There are several plugins, that can help with this. One example could be using `--leak-check=full` or similar options. There are also plugins for valgrind, that can enhance it detection capabilities.
- You say, that the application was reported to have a memory leak. How was this detected? Did the application detect this by itself. If it was detected by the application on it's own without any external tools, this probably means someone has added their own memory tracker inside the application. Custom memory tracker, memory pools etc. mess up valgrind and any other leak detection system very bad. So in case any custom memory handling is present in the application, your only choice is to either deactivate it (if possible) or to hook into this custom mechanism. How this could be done depends on your application only.
- Add your own memory tracker. For example in C++ it is possible to hook into new/delete calls and get them to track the memory. There are a couple of libraries you can use for this. You can also write your own new/delete replacement in about 500 LOC. If you decide to use this method, be sure to read a lot of tutorials on replacing new/delete, since there are several things that are unusual in the C++ world when attempting this task.
- What makes you so sure, there is an memory leak in the application (i.e. how was this detected)? If a tool just reported huge numbers of allocated memory, this might not even mean, there is an actual memory leak. A memory leak means that the handles to the memory are lost and hence it becomes impossible to every reach and free that memory again. In case your application just get's a lot of memory and keeps it accessible, you probably have a completely different problem. For example you simply might use an algorithm with a bad space complexity at one point or the other, leading to many allocations. In this case you will not need a leak detector, but rather a memory profiler, which gives you more detailed overview of the memory footprint of the code parts. However I have never used a profiler for this kind of task before, so I cannot give you any more hints on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all memory allocation calls with calls to your own allocation methods, which should call original methods and at the same time count memory usage and where it was allocated. This will allow you to find the leaks and eliminate them by hand.

There might also be automated tools that allow you to do this - not sure, haven't used any. But this method works.

Comment: I am sorry to say that i am not satisfied with the answer.

Comment: I have no problem with that... :-D Hope you find a better one (LiKao's answer looks promising).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might also consider using [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) (that is using `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` etc... and not bother about `free`-ing data).